# Elastic search combine match and should

Tags: elasticsearch, search, elasticsearch-dsl

I want to create a query where i can use match, and that match should only consider rows where another field value is null or some specific value.

So something like:

```
where field1 like 'string' and field2 is null or field2 = 123
```

Is that possible in JS client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a combination of [`bool/must/should`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html) along with the [exists](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-exists-query.html) and [wildcard query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-wildcard-query.html)

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "wildcard": {
            "field1": "string*"
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "term": {
                  "field2": 123
                }
              },
              {
                "bool": {
                  "must_not": {
                    "exists": {
                      "field": "field2"
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes this is what i needed!
The thing is that i want to use match instead of wildcard, and use fuzziness as well.
So just instead of wildcard, i created a match and it works!

The bad thing in match is that if a string has multiple SAME words, it prioritise those.